# Can I get a Yongnuo YN622C to trigger a Nissin Di700 in hss?

Tags: flash, wireless-triggers, yongnuo, nissin

I've recently bought a Nissin Di700 flash that has HSS feature.

I ask confirmation to those who have been able to try them both if with two tranceiver yongnuo yn-622C I can remotely control the Nissin in HSS?

Just for completeness I have a canon 7d.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the Nissin Di700, but the YN-622C triggers can communicate high speed sync, so it should work.

However if this is your first/only flash, you might be better off returning the Di700 and getting [a Di700**A** and the Nissin Air 1 Commander](http://flashhavoc.com/nissin-air-1-commander-di700a-flash-announced/), so you'll have a built-in receiver, rather than using an add-on one. The Di700A is the same price as the Di700 on B&H. The YN-622s will give you more flexibility in what lighting gear you might want to add to your triggering system, but built-in receivers have the advantage that you don't need to worry about external triggers or additional batteries.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of Di700A and Air 1 but I'm from Italy and it's not possible to know when these version will be sold :(. Here's why the question on the compatibility with yn-622C.

Comment: and `it should work` isn't enough :(.

Comment: @Christian Then maybe you should have bought a YN-568EXII. :) Use reports of the 622C with the 568EX are legion.

Comment: yes sure... when I bought the nissin I missing to think about radio trigger ;) was a quick shopping!

Comment: Since it understands the Canon protocols, it should work. Apparently the Nissin 866Di works, so it is a good bet this one will as well. http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1387509

Comment: OTOH, Di622 have had issues with the YN-622C, and there's this: http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?p=17118180

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I just bought a YN622C-TX + 2x YN622C and the TX DOES NOT trigger the Nissins correctly. Neither in HSS nor normal mode. However the YN622C triggers the other one just fine. Its somehow strange that Yongnuo doesn't get it right to trigger their own devices.

What I had to do was add the latest firmware to the TX, which requires you to have a special cable and some additional hassle. However when I updated it to the lastes FW, it triggered the Cs just fine.